# MAGMA-question concerning dual modules of bimodules

Tags: magma, bimodules

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H_1,H_2\leq G$.

Let char$(k)=p>0$, $k$ a field, large enough.

Let $T$ be a $(kH_1, kH_2)$-bimodule given in MAGMA.

Moreover, let $T$ be finitely generated projective as left $kH_1$-module.

Then, $T$ has a left dual $\widetilde{T}:=\text{Hom}_{kH_1}(T,kH_1)$.

I'd like to ask the following question:

> Is there a way to access / construct this dual module $\widetilde{T}$ as $(kH_2,kH_1)$-bimodule with MAGMA?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What you call the left dual is isomorphic as a bimodule to the vector space dual $\text{Hom}_k (T,k)$. Does that help?